# Java "incompatible types" error with Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new).reversed()

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, comparator, bigdecimal

I'm working on a problem where you are given a `String[]` containing numbers that are all formatted differently - e.g. "9", "-100", "56.6", "0.12", ".12", "02.34", "000.000", etc. The idea being that you need to sort the array in descending order while maintaining the given format. There are also null values in there. I have solved the problem multiple ways, but I ran into a problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I originally solved the problem using the following logic:

```java
Comparator<String> com = (x, y) -> new BigDecimal(y).compareTo(new BigDecimal(x));
 
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null).sorted(com).toArray(String[]::new);
```

I then tried to apply similar logic, which is where things broke down:

```java
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null).sorted(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new).reversed()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

This threw the following error:

```
java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
    (argument mismatch; invalid constructor reference
      no suitable constructor found for BigDecimal(java.lang.Object)
          constructor java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(char[]) is not applicable
            (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to char[])
          constructor java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(java.lang.String) is not applicable
            (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
          constructor java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(double) is not applicable
            (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to double)
```

I honestly can't make heads or tails of this. Disclaimer, I'm still pretty new to working with streams. I would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions need types. For example:

```
Object o = 5;
```

'5' is an expression. Its type is `int`. This is valid java code, but the type of the expression remains `int`; the fact that its being assigned to a variable of type `Object` does not change this. The compiler applies auto-boxing (assumes you meant to write `Object o = Integer.valueOf(5)`), and thus the desugared type of that expression becomes `Integer`, which is a subtype of Object and therefore can be assigned to variable o.

The thing about lambdas (`(x, y) -> foo`) and function references (`something::methodName`) is that they, too, are values, and therefore they, too, need to have a type.

And therein lies the rub. Java is designed so that there aren't generalized functional types. Instead, java checks the context *around* the method reference or lambda and checks: Which functional interface type is required here? - and then assumes that's the type that lambda/functional type is meant to have, and **only then** does the compiler actually parse the content of the lambda/method ref.

It has to do it this way, after all, `(x) -> x.toLowerCase().length() < 5` or whatever has to be a compiler error *unless* the type of `x` is `String` or something else with a `toLowerCase()` method, so to even begin to compile this, the compiler needs to know x is of type `String` but it can't know that unless the context *around* the `x -> x.toLowerCase().length() < 5` expression gives the compiler enough info to e.g. infer that the thing is meant to be a `Predicate<String>`.

The compiler does this by going inside-out, then outside-in, then inside-out again: First the compiler zooms in on everything and assigns types to it (i.e. in `Object o = 5;`, the compiler zooms in on the 5, it knows what type that is (`int`), and then zooms back out and figures out that auto-boxing is needed) - that's inside-out.

With lambdas/methodrefs, the compiler doesn't go any further than 'some lambda / some methodref, with unknown types' and doesn't try to parse the content at all. With that info it continues (and e.g. figures out which of a bunch of overloaded methods you meant), and only if that determines a single unique functional interface, that interface is applied and the lambda/methodref is parsed in that light.

A functional interface is any interface where you list all methods, remove anything with a default impl, remove anything that `j.l.Object` already has, and if there is precisely 1 method left over - then that is a functional interface, and you can implement it using lambda syntax or methodref syntax.

Here, if you wrote:

```
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null).sorted(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

All is well: `BigDecimal::new` is first treated as 'some methodref', then `Comparator.comparing` is checked, which determines that the argument has to be of type `Comparator<? super X>` where X isn't clear yet, so the compiler continues and eventually figures out that `s` is a `String[]`, from there it determines that therefore `Stream.of(s)` is a `Stream<String>`, therefore `Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null)` is a `Stream<String>`, and from there that the argument to calling `.sorted()` on that must be `Comparator<? super String>`, and picks the most specific bound (`String`), and figures out that the argument needs to be a `Function<String, Z extends Comparable<Z>` where Z can be anything.

That's all *very very* complicated but the compiler manages to get that far, and in that light, parsed `BigDecimal::new` and figures it out: That is an implementation of `Function<String, BigDecimal>`, and BigDecimal is indeed a valid type for Z here. The code compiles and works.

Now go back to what you have (which tosses a `reversed()` in the mix) and you've exceeding the compiler's abilities to figure this out. It decides to go ahead and 'parse' `BigDecimal::new` with less info (because it needs to figure out what `.reversed()` does before it can figure out the context around it), so it tries its best and parses it as a `Function<Object, Z extends Comparable<Z>>` and `BigDecimal::new` doesn't 'fit' that type (as `new BigDecimal(anyObject)` doesn't exist).

And that's the error you see.

Solving it:

You need to tell the compiler about that context 'sooner'. In your original code, you do that by assigning the comparator to a variable - because now the type of the variable serves as context. You can do that in the second snippet too:

```
Comparator<String> byValue = Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new);
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null).sorted(byValue.reversed()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description! While very complex this is exactly what I needed to hear. I've never had this explained in such detail. If you are able, could you point me in the direction of documentation around the subject that I could dig into further. I can't seem to find anything on the web that goes into even a fraction of the detail you just did. Even if it's a book, I'm good for anything.

Comment: The Java Lang Spec, but that's some fairly complicated material.

Comment: I do think extracting the comparator here reads better, but another option is to explicitly tell Java the type of the generics used by `Comparator.comparing`: `Comparator.<String, BigDecimal>comparing(BigDecimal::new)`.  All together, that becomes `s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null).sorted(Comparator.<String, BigDecimal>comparing(BigDecimal::new).reversed()).toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the second argument `Comparator.reverseOrder()` instead of `Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new).reversed()`

```
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

### Incorrect <s>Short</s> version:

(Updated after comments)

This codebase is sorting Strings, not BigDecimal objects! Please don't use it:

```
s = Stream.of(s).filter(x -> x != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: All good, but how would the 'short version' work if the elements have not been mapped into numbers?

Comment: The short version doesn't work because it sorts 'alphabetically', instead of what OP wants, which is 'treat the string as a number then sort _that_'. The second argument part is a good idea though.

Comment: Thank you  @rzwitserloot for your help!
 I was wrong. The short version is totally incorrect. I fixed the second part of the answer

Comment: @g00se , Sorry, the short version is incorrect! It is sorting String objects (not BigDecimal objects). I fixed the second part of the answer. Thank you!